# Python 3.5: PIL Image.fromarray producing nonsense image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have an RGB image. When I import this image, I convert it to HSV using `matplotlib.color` and save the resulting array in a dict. When I want to display this image, I use `Image.fromarray` with `mode = 'HSV'`. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but when the image is displayed, I get a mess (seen below along with code). Any help is appreciated. The code snippets below are roughly what happens in order to any given set of imported images.

RGB to HSV Code:

```
from skimage import io 
import matplotlib.colors as mpclr
import glob
import os 
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

types = ("\*.tif", "\*.jpg", "\*.ppm")
imagePath = []

def importAllImgs(folderPath):

    for ext in types:
        imagePath.extend(glob.glob(folderPath + ext))


    im_coll = io.ImageCollection(imagePath, conserve_memory = True)
    im_array = []    

    for i in range(len(im_coll)):
        #CONVERSION HAPPENS HERE
        image = im_coll[i]
        fltImg = np.around((np.array(image)/255.0), decimals = 2)
        imgHSV = mpclr.rgb_to_hsv(fltImg)

        im_array.append(imgHSV)  

    return im_array, imagePath
```

Storage of Data:

```
def organizeAllData(self, imgArrList, imgPathList):

    self.allImages = dict()            
    self.imageKeys = imgPathList

    for i in range(len(imgPathList)):

        self.allImages[imgPathList[i]] = {'H': imgArrList[i][:, :, 0],
                                            'S': imgArrList[i][:, :, 1],
                                            'V': imgArrList[i][:, :, 2]}


    self.hsvValues = []
    self.labelValues = [] 

    return self.allImages
```

Construction of array for displaying image:

```
def getImage(self, imageOfInterest):

    H = self.allImages[imageOfInterest]['H'][:,:]
    S = self.allImages[imageOfInterest]['S'][:,:]
    V = self.allImages[imageOfInterest]['V'][:,:]

    imgArray = np.dstack((H,S,V))

    return imgArray
```

Displaying of Image:

```
    preImArray = halThrThsnd.getImage(self.imagePaths[self.imageIndex])
    self.preIm = Image.fromarray(preImArray, 'HSV')
```

And finally, the resulting image:

[image]

Comment: Why not doing all the image-stuff within scikit-image (as you are already importing it)? It's much more specialized,so it's less likely that you make an error. Depending on color-dimensions and color-formats, it can be cumbersome to keep the right types for all these operations (e.g. internal floats or unsigned integers). It of course also can do the color-conversion as well as outputting a current image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per user sascha's comment (see below question), I decided to normalize the libraries I'm using for HSV conversion. Once I did that, I got normal images no problem. It turns out that depending on what library you use for image conversion, you will get different HSV value ranges. Some libraries will produce a range from 0 to 1. Others will produce a range from 0 to 255.

Tl;dr: Used the same library across all processes, got a good image.